# Angular find all Services of a type

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular9

do you have an idea how I can get all Services of a type in Angular ?

I have a base class for the services and I want to find all registered services that are inherited from the base service.

Using:

```
this.injector.get(SERVICE)
```

I can only get them if I know them all.

I'm looking for something like:

```
listofAllChilds = this.injector.getAll(BASESERVICE)
```

Is there something like this out there ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: AFAIK Not. But can you explain why you want this? Maybe there is another way to solve your problem.

Comment: It's more a less a matter of convenience, I did not want to makes changes to a certain part of the applications as more services are added.

Thanks for your reply :)